# How do multiple reducers output only one part-file in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

In my map-reduce job, I use 4 reducers to implement the reducer jobs. So by doing this, the final output will generate 4 part-files.: part-0000 part-0001 part-0002 part-0003

My question is how can I set the configuration of hadoop to output only one part-file, although the hadoop use 4 reducers to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't the behaviour expected from hadoop. But you may use `MultipleOutputs` to your advantage here.
Create one named output and use that in all your reducers to get the final output in one file itself. It's javadoc itself suggest the following:

```
 JobConf conf = new JobConf();

 conf.setInputPath(inDir);
 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, outDir);

 conf.setMapperClass(MOMap.class);
 conf.setReducerClass(MOReduce.class);
 ...

 // Defines additional single text based output 'text' for the job
 MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(conf, "text", TextOutputFormat.class,
 LongWritable.class, Text.class);;
 ...

 JobClient jc = new JobClient();
 RunningJob job = jc.submitJob(conf);

 ...
```

Job configuration usage pattern is:

```
public class MOReduce implements
   Reducer<WritableComparable, Writable> {
 private MultipleOutputs mos;

 public void configure(JobConf conf) {
 ...
 mos = new MultipleOutputs(conf);
 }

 public void reduce(WritableComparable key, Iterator<Writable> values,
 OutputCollector output, Reporter reporter)
 throws IOException {
 ...
 mos.getCollector("text", reporter).collect(key, new Text("Hello"));
 ...
 }

 public void close() throws IOException {
 mos.close();
 ...
 }

 }
```

If you are using the new `mapreduce` API then see [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html).

Comment: I got it! And I understand it's not recommended that multiple reducers output only one file. Thanks @Amar

Answer (score -1):

```
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(conf, "text", TextOutputFormat.class,
 LongWritable.class, Text.class);
```

Here `text` is output directory or single large file named `text` ?