# Control number of hadoop mapper output files

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a job for hadoop. When the job is stated, i have some number of mappers started. And each mapper write some file to disk, like part-m-00000, part-m-00001. As I understand, each mapper create one part file. I have big amount of data, so there must be more than one mapper, but can I somehow control number of this output files? I mean, hadoop will start, for example 10 mappers, but there will be only three part files?

I found this post 
[How do multiple reducers output only one part-file in Hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346143/how-do-multiple-reducers-output-only-one-part-file-in-hadoop)
But there is using old version of hadoop library. I'm using classes from org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.* and not from org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*

I'm using hadoop version 0.20, and hadoop-core:1.2.0.jar

Is there any possibility to do this, using new hadoop API?

Comment: You can write to one or more output files (as you wish) with MultipleOutputFormat from different mappers to HDFS. I hope that clears the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of output files equals to the number of reducers or the number of the mappers if there aren't any reducers.

You can add a single reducer to your job so that the output from all the mappers will be directed to it and your get a single output file. Note that will be less efficient as all the data (output of mappers) will be sent over the wire (network IO) to the node where the reducer will run. Also since a single process will (eventually) get all the data it would probably run slower.

By the wat,the fact that there are multiple parts shouldn't be very  significant as you can pass the directory containing them to subsequent jobs

Comment: In my case, I don't have reducers at all, so I'm trying to do this with out using reducers.

Comment: I understand - but essentially what you are trying to do is equivalent to adding a reducer to sum up all the output from all the mappers

Comment: Not exactly what I want, but I think, it the best answer from proposed. Thank you/

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure you can do it (your link is about multiple outputs not converging to only one), and why use only one output ? you will lose all parallelism on sort ?

Im also working on big files (~10GB each) and my MR process almost 100GB each. So to lower Map numbers, I set a higher value of block size in hdfs (applies only to newer files) and a higher value of `mapred.min.split.size` in `mapred-site.xml`

Comment: I do not need reduce tasks to start. I will process output file by another job (not hadoop job), so do not need any sort. I just want read one big file instead of large number of small output files.

Comment: After looking at @JtheRocker comment and the doc linked, i think he's right. The method which build the output file name has several parameters that seems to allow you to always write in same file (ie: having only 1 output file for N maps).

Comment: I mean getInputFileBasedOutputFileName by method ;)

Comment: getInputFileBasedOutputFileName  is in the old API org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultipleTextOutputFormat, and I don't want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [MultipleOutputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html)

Part of what Javadoc says:

> This abstract class extends the FileOutputFormat, allowing to write
>   the output data to different output files.

Both Mapper and Reducer can use this.

Check [this link](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html#getInputFileBasedOutputFileName%28org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf,%20java.lang.String%29) for how you can specify a output file name **or more** from different mappers to output to HDFS.

**NOTE: And, moreover, make sure you don't use context.write() so that, 10 files from 10 mapper don't get created. Use only MultipleOutputFormat to output.**

Comment: Using MultipleOutputStream in mapper I will get : file1-m-00000, file1-m-00001 and so on.

Comment: MultipleOutputFormat is the exact opposite of what the OP is asking for, it allows even *more* individual output files.

Comment: @Keith - you are wrong. MultipleOutputFormat can write to only specific number of files from mappers as the OP wants. Don't down vote if you aren't sure please.

Comment: It sounds to me like the OP wants to *control* the number of output files, not have *exactly one* output file.  He says "but can I somehow control number of this output files? I mean, hadoop will start, for example 10 mappers, but there will be only three part files?"  Generally one can do this by specifying the number of reducers.   I don't know how 10 mappers on 10 physical machines would write to the same three files using only a custom output format.

Comment: @user2281439/@Keith: You can write to one or more output files (as you wish) with MultipleOutputFormat from different mappers to HDFS. I hope that clears the confusion.

Comment: Will anyone want to specify why the down vote? Common that's rude

Comment: Also, MultipleOutputFormat is in the old API, which I don't want to use

Comment: @SSaikia_JtheRocker it was downvoted as it was incorrect. If you write to a single file, it still gets split into part files - which is what the OP wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

If the job has no reducers, partitioners and combiners, each mapper outputs one output file. At some point, you should run some post processing to collect the outputs into large file.