# Hadoop Combine Multiple part files into single file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Currently I have

`part-00001 
 part-00002`

I know that using `hdfs -getmerge` is the best way to combine those files into a single one. However, is it possible to do it **programmatically**?

I've tried using [MultipleOutput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346143/how-do-multiple-reducers-output-only-one-part-file-in-hadoop), but it is not working. I've also tried writing my own `CustomOutputFormat` however due to multiple reducers during writing it to the file in parallel it gives `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException` error when closing the Dataoutputstream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use the [FileSystem class](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) from your java code, and probably calling the [concat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#concat%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path[]%29) method is all you need.

MultipleOutput does almost the opposite. Instead of having `part-xxxxx` files, it also produces customly named files, which typically means more files than before.

CustomOuputFormat is also not a good idea, since in any case, you will have as many output files as the number of reducers. The output format will not change that.

Using a single reducer (`setNumReduceTasks(1)`) could be a working solution, but unnecessarily expensive, since it "kills" parallelism (all the data are processed by a single task). Consider using it only if your data is rather small, otherwise avoid it.

Another solution would be to simply call `hdfs -getmerge` as a shell command from your java code, after the MapReduce job is complete.

Comment: This is the most complete solutions listed down. Thanks!

Comment: @Meaniegy I'm glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it programmatically as its managed by Hadoop and these files are created depends on the number of reducers configured .
 Why do you need to merge these files programatically ? 
If for input as another job , you can always mention the directory as input and use `CombineInputFormat` if there are lot of small part- files  . 
Otherwise `hdfs -getmerge` is the best option if you want to merge your own .